# Override will-change bootstrap property

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to override will-change: transform property. There is infinity scroll which includes this property. I want to display a modal when someone click a button, but my modal is like behind another layer. When this property is deselected (with chrome inspect element) the modal is working well. So I try to add will-change: auto !important to my hole container (that holds the button and modal divs), but that doesn't work at all. So the question is why and how could I fix it?

Comment: some bootstrap properties cannot be overridden so you probably needto make changes in the bootstrap.css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution - it's needed to add what will-change property you want as !important just into the element that bootstrap added it. But be careful - sometimes it could cause some shits.

Answer (score 1):

put modal in footer div and on button click add css attribute z-index: 100;  to modal and on modal close event make to z-index: -1;